# CSS style text align with the label

Tags: html, css

How do I adjust the text starting with "It looks great if tucked in neat and straight. YES,I recommend this product " same with "The material for the..."

```
<span class="titlerm">Description:</span>
<span style="margin-left:40px; text-align:justify;">  
<asp:Label ID="productreviewLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("productreview") %>' /
</span>
```

The result looks like below:

[image]

The result I want is:

[image]

Comment: have you tried taking the margin-left out completely? Like, just not have it all together? Please restate the question a little better, or else it will risk being shut down.

Comment: Mickey, try increasing the font size of the text block to give such an effect. Also, make Description H4 .

Comment: haven solve http://jsfiddle.net/michael5119/g3RQY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ..

```
<span class="title">Description:</span>
<span class="description">  
   <asp:Label ID="productreviewLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("productreview") %>' /
</span>
```

Css -

```
.title {
float:left;
width:20%;
font-weight:bold;
}

.description{
float:left;
width:80%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b3UJu/2/)

Answer (score 2):

HTML and CSS code

```
<span class="titlerm" style=" width:6%; display:block; float:left; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><strong>Description:</strong></span>
<span style=" display:block; width:94%; float:left; text-align:justify; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">  
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</span>
```

Try this code

Comment: Here is slightly modified code: http://jsfiddle.net/theStudent/yb9Bc/ it works. I would suggest adding FIXED size to Description part, once it shrinks the text overlaps

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/d6vsN/

HTML:

```
<span class="titlerm"><strong>Description:</strong></span>
<span class="description">  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum ex magni provident harum saepe perspiciatis veniam totam doloribus dolorem blanditiis.
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.titlerm {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.description {
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: I also like this solution because of individual CSS, however I would recommend FIXED width for Description and fixing <Strong> to CSS